# React-Grid-Layout: How to re-render items on resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) and [react-custom-scrollbars](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) to create a grid of panels. Here's a simplifed version of the code:

```
class GridLayoutWithScrollableItems extends React.Component {

    onResize() {
        this.setState({forceRenderAfterResize: Date.now()})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ReactGridLayout width={900} onResize={this.onResize.bind(this)}>
                <div key="a">
                    <Scrollbars>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ....</p>
                    </Scrollbars>
                </div>
                <div key="b">
                    <Scrollbars>
                        <p>Aenean purus magna ...</p>
                    </Scrollbars>
                </div>
            </ReactGridLayout>
        )
    }
}
```

Works as expected except resizing: `Scrollbars` will only update its bars when it is re-rendered which is why I am setting that dummy state variable `forceRenderAfterResize`.

What would be the best way to achieve this? The solution above feels a bit clumsy and will also re-render all items instead of just the one that was resized.

Answer (score 0):

Call [forceUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) in your onResize method. Some might try to argue if they've read the react docs incorrectly, that setting state is preferred over forcingUpdate, but that's only when that state is actual state that matters, and setState does not guarantee a re-render if custom shouldComponentUpdate logic is implemented. No reason to muddy your state over UI modifications made via the UI, when you specifically want to re-render if the browser determines a resize:

```
onResize() {
   this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks CH, that is certainly clearer than introducing a dummy variable. I would still prefer a more focused solution where perhaps react-grid-layout's [GridItem](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/lib/GridItem.jsx) somehow communicates with react-custom-scrolllbar's [Scrollbars](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/blob/master/src/Scrollbars/index.js) component. Resizing only affects the content of one of the panels of the grid so there's no need to render all of them. That said, this might well be premature optimization on my part.